# Is there a way to filter Wikipedia tables?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki, greasemonkey

I'm looking for a way to filter tables often found in Wikipedia articles, so I can compare only the rows (and columns) I'm interested in.

Is there either

1. a built-in feature in the Wikipedia engine that I'm not aware of
2. or a browser plugin that supports this

The features I can think of are:

- Filter by column value
- Hide columns
- Multilevel sorting

Comment: Ahhh... the off-topic minefield. See point 3 in the first table. I'm asking for something specific to Wikipedia. In fact a Greasemonkey script would do, but haven't been able to find one

Answer (score 12):

If you place [this formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339) in a cell within Google Sheet, it will scrape the tabular data from this Wikipedia article link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India", "table", 4)
```

Once you have the data within Google Sheet, you can filter by column value (select column header, choose *Filter* from *Data* menu) & hide column (select column, choose *Hide column* from context menu)

[image: Google Sheets screen shot]

Comment: You can also just copy and paste it into Sheets.

Comment: Yes, the tabular data can be copy-pasted but if the data is dynamic, using a formula may be a better option. Bookmarklets like this one can also manipulate data within tables  directly on the source web page - https://www.phpied.com/reactivetable-bookmarklet/

Answer (score 5):

The [Wikipedia Table filter](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/137939) Greasemonkey script does what you want:

> Script Summary: Filters wikipedia tables by removing all rows that have an undesired value, or by deleting certain rows and columns.

You may need to add the `https` version of the wikiedia URL to the script's included pages filter list to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Tables? Do you mean the infoboxes? You should probably use Wikidata http://wikidata.org/w/api.php and extract the information from there (it will be cleaner), then present it how you prefer.

Otherwise, you can sprinkle `display: none` everywhere on appropriate IDs and classes for the tables in question, but it's going to be an endless chase of unstructured information.